# Updating array value on input change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to update my quantity values saved in array so when i update quantity it is also saved after refresh. Problem is that when i am always updating same item, even when i have multiple items in cart and i try to change quantity of each, it changes quantity of only one item. I am bit lost in these loops, i tried to move the update section out of while but it didnt help. Also when I don't have `unset($_POST['qt'])` it changes all items quantity in cart, which is wrong.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $index => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $id => $quantity) {

        $sql = "SELECT name, image, quantity, price  FROM product WHERE product.id_p = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $image, $maxquantity, $price);
        while($stmt->fetch()) : ?>  
            <tr>
            <td><?=$image?></td>
            <td><?=$name?></td>
            <td><?=$id?></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control quantitycart" data-id="<?=$id?>" min="1" max="<?=$maxquantity?>" data-min="1" data-max="<?=$maxquantity?>" name="quantitycart" value="<?=$quantity = ($quantity > $maxquantity) ? $maxquantity : $quantity; ?>"/></td>
            <td>€<span class="price"><?=$price * $quantity?></span>
            <input type="hidden" class="real_price" value="<?=$price?>"/></td>
            <td><a href="cart.php?delete=<?=$id; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><?=$id?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"/></a></td>
            <tr>




        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['qt']) && isset($_POST['idupd'])){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$index][$_POST['idupd']] = $_POST['qt'];
            unset($_POST['qt']);
            unset($_POST['idupd']);

        }

        endwhile;

        $stmt->close(); }

    }
}
```

JS

```
    $('.quantitycart').change(function(){
var container = $(this).parents('tr');
var price = container.find('.real_price').val() * 1;
var qty = $(this).val() * 1;
var total = price * qty;
var id = $(this).data('id');
container.find('.price').html(total);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {qt: qty, idupd: id},
    url: 'includes/cartbody.php',
    success: function(data){

    }
});
});
```

EDIT:

```
if(isset($_POST['qt']) && isset($_POST['idupd'])){
                $_SESSION['cart'][$index][$_POST['idupd']] = $_POST['qt'];
                unset($_POST['qt']);
                unset($_POST['idupd']);

            }
```

Comment: You only send the quantity, but what about the id of the product that you want to change the quantity to?

Comment: I get it in the foreach loop or no ?

Comment: even if you get it in the foreach - how do you know that a quantity is related to that specific id?

Comment: mmm, true. So I added `data-id="<?=$id?>"` to my input, get it in JS and send it via ajax, it is changing only values that i want, but it is also copying my array.I edited OP with how i try to update the array.

Comment: And where do you post the `idupd`?

Comment: I updated whole op with what i have now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123799/discussion-between-dekel-and-rtom).